# ODBC connection to ACCDB in web.config

Tags: asp.net, connection, odbc, web-config

Want to connect to ACCDB file as an ODBC (rather than OleDb) data source in ASP.NET but struggling with the connection string. As I plan to deploy the web app from Visual Studio 2019 to Azure, I need something that can make the journey.

Here's what I tried from connectionstrings.com (I discovered not all of those strings are up to date or necessarily convenient for insertion to web.config):

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.accdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;
```

This returns `keyword not supported: driver` from IIS Express where I'm doing development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, that looks ok:

I would suggest this:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
dbq=C:\test\test44.accdb;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;
maxbuffersize=2048;maxscanrows=8;pagetimeout=5;safetransactions=0;
threads=3;uid=admin;usercommitsync=Yes
```

the above is what the connection builder in Visual Studio spits out.
and you have Dbq - carefull - caps I believe matters - so try dbq.

Next up:
HUGE HUGE elephant in the room.

are you using a x32 bit driver, or the x64 bit one? YOU MUST match your project bit size (code compile) settings to the driver (YOU MUST!!!).

So this:

[image]

you MUST set and force your project to run as x32 bits. (or perhaps install the x64 bit version of Access drivers. AND BE careful. If you are running the x64 bit versions of the drivers, and use Test connection with Visual Studio? It will always fail since VS runs as a x32 bit applcation. you MUST RUN the applcation to test the connection - NOT use test connection with VS connection builders (you might not be using them, but if you are, just trying to save you a day of work wasted).

so, create a x32 config project. And thus this now:

[image]

And I assume your sample connection using c: or "root" of the drive is a JUST a example, since most windows now don't allow a file to be used directly from c: root location.

Comment: *such* a huge elephant ... lol ... are we not 12 years out from the first introduction of Office x64?? Any way, @albert-d-kallal BIG THANKS for all the walkthroughs and cautionary notes! I did abandon this project as the performance (and security) of an .accdb file on a web server is pretty poor, whether under OLE DB or (worse) ODBC. Probably something to do with the "great 32/64 divide".

Comment: Actually, odbc still remains the viable choice. Oledb and even .net SQL providers are not really industry standards, and not platform netural. But odbc is not limited to windows and is in fact cross platform and enjoys support beyond windows by most vendors. And access performance actually can be rather good since it runs in process on the web server. However given so many available server based databases, and issues if threading? Hard to make a case for using access database for web sites. But good performance will be good designs and not the fault of the database in near all cases.

Comment: Today near all web sites run as x64 bits, so this does suggest that x64 access should be used. However there are great migration tools such as SQL migration assistant for access to SQL server, and that tool is a free download from ms. So I would migration out of access since such great tools exist for this purpose.